# How to create a 2 column layout in xhtml without CSS

Tags: html, xhtml

Need your help writing the proper code for a 2 column layout in XHTML using online inline styling.

Essentially I am trying to redesign the overview page of my companies wiki to have a 2 column layout with links in each column that takes users into a different section of the wiki.

Since I don't have much knowledge of XHTML, I'm using HTML + a converter. When I convert the HTML to XHTML and input it  into the wiki page, I end up with my block elements overlapping one another. Here's what I've written, any pointers would be appreciated:

```
<body>
<div id="left" style="display: block;"> 
    <ul style="float:left; width:300px; height:400px;">
        <a href=""> 
        <img src=""> </a> </br>

        <h4>Ways to Get Involved</h4> </br>
        <a href="">Design Thinking with Jacquelyn</a> </br>
        <a href="">Running Meetings </a> </br>
        <a href="">Preparing and Running Playbacks</a> </br>
        <a href="">Working with Users</a> </br>
        <a href="">See all topics</a> </br>

        <a href=""> 
        <img src=""> </a> </br>


        <a href=""> </br> Find and share useful tools for day-to-day design     work</a> </br>  

    </ul>

</div>



<div id="right" style="float: left; width: 300px; height:400px;"> 
    <ul style="float:left">
      <a href=""> 
        <img src=""> </a> </br>

        <h4>Latest Posts</h4>
        <a href="">Slimming down on features for a more delightful experience</a> </br>
        <a href="">CitiBike: First 100 Days Visualized</a> </br>
        <a href="">Development and Design Go Hand-in-Hand When Creating Smarter Cities</a> </br>
        <a href="">Story 2.0: The Surprising Thing About the Next Wave of Narrative</a> </br>
        <a href="">See all blog posts</a> </br>

          <a href=""> 
        <img src=""> </a> </br>

        <a href="">Get engaged, educated and empowered to do Design Thinking</a>
```

Anyway-- any/ all help very much appreciated. Am under EOD Friday (Today) deadline on this.

Comment: XHTML is just HTML with proper closing tags.  You should use stylesheets, not inline `style=""` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the container divs to `width="45%"`. This will let them both fit in the overall 100% of the screen, but will also allow some room for padding.

Floating one left and the other right will help, I guess. I would rather use `display:inline-block;` though.

Here, have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/DwFsT/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use :

`style="float: left; width: 300px; height:400px;`"

on the outer DIVs only. Do not float the contents (UL)

BTW: Inline styles *are* CSS too.

Comment: Thanks guys- I'll give these two suggestions a go.

Comment: Ok- I've tried the Div suggestion that @Agony made and that + using % seems to have worked. 

Am also now going to make these into 4 separate divs (left, bottom left, right, bottom right) to see if that will help better align the content -- which right now is all outta whack.. Thanks for your help!